# Coloring axvspan from range of colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

**Background**

I am trying to plot consecutive colored areas in **Python** using **matplotlib**. I use (imagine i being some iteration variable)

```
axvspan(from_x[i], to_x[i], color=my_color[i])
```

to plot this.

Now, I need a general way to say "plot from green to increasingly more red given N areas to be plotted next to each other".

```
i = 0: area is green,
i = 1: area is green but with some red,
etc.
i = N: area is red.
```

You get the point.

**Question**
Sure, if N was fixed I could just manually put in the rgb values, but it is not. I have looked up ways to do this if plotting lines etc. but I am not sure how to do this for axvspan(...) and specifically how to get the green to red feature. Most examples I found was regarding color maps which I am not sure I want to use here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `(r,g,b)` tuple for the color, so we can just increase the red and decrease the green as we move through the loop.

Obviously, you can manipulate `N` and the `from_x` and `to_x` arrays to suit your needs.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

N = 20

from_x = np.linspace(0,0.95,N)
to_x = from_x + 0.05

for i in range(N):
    ri = float(i)/float(N)
    gi = 1.-ri
    bi = 0.

    ax.axvspan(from_x[i], to_x[i], color=(ri,gi,bi))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @tom.
Should really be a built-in feature in pyplot imo.